# Can stream 'map' be used for such processing?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Can this be done with Stream|Map so that I wouldn't need to place result in external HashMap, but collect result with .collect(Collectors.toMap(...)); ?

```
Map<ReportType, Long> rep = new HashMap<>(); // result is here
Arrays.stream(rTypes).forEach(r -> rep.put(r.reportType, r.calcValue()));
```

Where `r.calcValue()` calculates the new result, that is placed then in map.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can use `Collectors#toMap()` here. Assuming `rTypes` contains `Report` instances:

```
Map<ReportType, Long> rep = Arrays.stream(rTypes)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Report::getReportType, Report::calcValue));
```

(You *do* have a `getReportType` method, right? :)

Comment: Note that if you have any duplicate report types here, this will fail with an IllegalStateException. (Your original example would have silently had one entry override another.)

Comment: @SamLindsay-Levine this is true. An alternate solution is to use `Collectors#groupingBy()` instead of `toMap()`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can be done like this, assuming `r.calcValue()` returns a `Long`:

```
Map<ReportType, Long> rep = Arrays.stream(rTypes)
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.reportType, r -> r.calcValue()));
```